# How to install jface manually in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jface

I want to develop my next application with the JFace toolkit.
So I tried to follow the steps from [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace) to configure an eclipse project.

But now I'm a little bit confused because of the following things:

1. The Plug-in Development Environment (PDE) was not installed in my eclipse, so I first installed it from the eclipse market place. But now I suddenly have more than two thousand JAR files in my eclipse plugins folder. Is this correct?
2. In the eclipse plugins folder I found the org.eclipse.jface_.jar but with the version number 3.10.2. Shouldn't it be a number of 4.1 beause I'm using Luna?
3. I don't understand the first step in the tutorial with the description of the dependencies. If I go to Window > Show View > PDE > Plug-ins and right click the org.eclipse.jface entry and open the dependency view then I see a list of entries so I think the dependencies are already set. Why I have to go to this view and what I have to do there?

I hope the next steps will be more easier to understand :-)

Comment: That tutorial is aimed at developing an app which just uses SWT+JFace. If you are trying to develop an Eclipse plugin it is not suitable.

Comment: @greg: I want to build a JFace-based app and only want to use eclipse as IDE for that. But the app should be a standalone app at the end.